# Swift Optional Checking "Unexpectedly found nil"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure why Swift is complaining that list1 = list1!.next unexpectedly found nil when my if statement checks if list1 != nil. Could anyone explain why checking if list1 != nil is not enough? I've tried changing it to

```
if list1 {
    list1 = list1!.next
}
```

but it suggested that I check using != nil

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/mbatilando/3d1b3e391418ac56b13c)

Here's my code:

```
class Node {
    var data: Int
    var next: Node?

    init (data: Int) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

func addReversed (var list1: Node?, var list2: Node?) -> Node {
    var carry = 0
    var head: Node? = nil
    var prev: Node? = nil
    while list1 != nil || list2 != nil {
        var newNode = addNode(list1, list2, &carry)
        appendNode(head, prev, newNode)
        if list1 != nil {
            list1 = list1!.next
        }
        if list2 != nil {
            list2 = list2!.next
        }
    }
    if carry > 0 {
        var carryNode = Node(data: carry)
        appendNode(head, prev, carryNode)
    }
    return head!
}
```

Comment: You can't say `if list1`. It is not a Bool. You cannot nil-check like that. (You could in very early Swift, but they abolished it, rightly.)

Comment: Could you describe Node a little more?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the crash line is that line?

Comment: A possible reason I see is because next is nil for the last node, but I would think that would be fine since I've declared it as an optional in the class definition (and I'm unwrapping list1, not list1.next).

Edit: Yes, I get the error; "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Yes, I agree. Let me ask you this, are there any weak references in this story?

Comment: There are no weak references

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the crash. That's why I'm asking if something else I don't know about might be going on.

Comment: How many iterations of the while loop do we get thru before we crash?

Comment: It always crashes on the last element of the linkedlist, where node.next = nil

Comment: You are returning `head!` but you have never assigned anything to it aside from nil

Comment: Also, are you sure the error is occurring from the list1!? I ask because your code never sets head to anything and in your return statement you unwrap head.

Comment: I modify head in appendNode. I've attached a gist of all the code I'm using. Thanks for the help

Comment: Modifying the variable in another function won't affect the local variable in this function

Comment: I think you are mutating `list1` or `list2` in code that we can't see.

Comment: I think your `appendNode` function is flawed.

Comment: A lot of your trouble here is coming from fighting Swift. When you find yourself using `!` a lot, you're going to have trouble. Passing lots of `inout` parameters is also a sure sign that you're fighting the language. This whole thing can be done with immutable data and no `!`s.

I went ahead and fixed some bugs and added some conveniences (without those, it'd be shorter than this solution as well). https://gist.github.com/rnapier/7a552b7f8f089b0d91f6 If you really want it to be mutable, you still can do it with no `!`s like this: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/7e3887ab248c43f0b44d

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you asked, but I think it may have a lot to do with the problem. I tested your Node and your basic `addReversed` code and I couldn't get a crash. But at that time I didn't have any of your other global functions, so I had to just comment them out while testing. Since I didn't crash, therefore I came to believe that the problem is *in* one of those global functions.

Then you published your gist, with the code to those global functions, and I can see immediately that this code is deeply flawed:

```
func appendNode(var head: Node?, var prev: Node?, node: Node) {
    if head == nil {
        head = node
    }
    if prev == nil {
        prev = node
    }
    else {
        prev!.next = node
        prev = node
    }
}
```

You seem to think that saying e.g. `prev = node` will replace the node that came in as `prev` with the node that came in as `node` in some outside world. It will not. These are the names of local variables only. So none of that code has any effect at all - except for `prev!.next = node`, because there you are mutating an instance that exists also in the outside world (because this is a reference type, a class instance).

If you want to replace the object that came in on a parameter with another object, you need an `inout` parameter.

For example:

```
class Dog {
    let name:String
    init(_ s:String) {
        name = s
    }
}

func replaceDog(var d:Dog) {
    d = Dog("Rover") // this is what you are doing
}

var d = Dog("Fido")
replaceDog(d)
d // still Fido
```

But:

```
class Dog {
    let name:String
    init(_ s:String) {
        name = s
    }
}

func replaceDog(inout d:Dog) {
    d = Dog("Rover")
}

var d = Dog("Fido")
replaceDog(&d)
d // Rover
```

Your code is full of this same false assumption, and I think, although I have not worked out the details, that this assumption is the cause of your difficulty here. My guess is that you got this linked list implementation from some other language that has pointers, but you are not using pointers in your implementation. The way to use pointers in Swift is with `inout`!